# Javascript/JQUERY local variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 pieces of code
Javascript:

```
function changeImage(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
        npath = document.getElementById("main_img").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
    }
}
```

and JQUERY

```
var bpath = npath.replace("_n", "_b");
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.prod_seeds_mimg_div').zoom({url: bpath});
});
```

I want to access `npath` variable from Javascript block, change it and use in JQUERY. But `npath` variable is not defined outside of Javascript. I've tried to make it global by skipping `var` and declare `npath` on top of two blocks (`var npath = "";`) but these methods are not helped.

Is there some way to access `npath` from JS and use it further?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share an example, you can use something like https://jsbin.com

Comment: Are these both in the same file? The way you show them declared in here, they are on the `window` object, and you should be fine.

Comment: What you are doing should work, assuming `changeImage` is executed before the code that needs npath. (but from the looks of it, it probably isn't.)

Comment: https://jsbin.com/pafejageqe/edit?html,js,output
here's exsmple with html, but it is fully works because I  also use PHP there

Yes, both blocks of code in the same file

Comment: better solution would just be to use jQuery for everything you're trying to do there. It's all quite easily done with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Try to use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.prod_seeds_mimg_div').zoom({url: $('#main_img').attr('src')});

  $('div.prod_seeds_oimg_div img').on('click', function(){
    changeImage($(this).attr('src'));
  });

});

function changeImage(imagePath){
  $('#main_img').attr('src', imagePath);
  $('.prod_seeds_mimg_div').zoom({url: imagePath});
}
```

And remember to remove the `changeImage` onClick trigger from your HTML source.

Comment: I don't recommend this because it pollutes the global namespace, but it would work.